# Objective-C Convert a string to date and time format

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

I have an issue of getting a date on converting to `NSDate`. My requirement is that I have a string like @"01-01-2016 22:22:22" and i want to convert it into date form. Then check the device time format and change its form according to that. Below is my code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateform=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateform setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateform setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateform setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];


NSString *timeStr=@"01-01-2016 22:22:22"; //sample date
NSDate *dt=[dateform dateFromString:timeStr];

NSString *dateString=[dateform stringFromDate:dt];
NSRange *amRange=[dateString rangeOfString:[dateform AMSymbol]];
NSRange *pmRange=[dateString rangeOfString:[dateform PMSymbol]];
BOOL is12h=(amRange.location==NSNotFound && pmRange.location==NSNotFound);
if(is12h)
{
   [dateform setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm:ss"];
}
else
{
   [dateform setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
}
dateString=[dateformatter stringFromDate:dt];
```

`NSDate *dt=[dateform dateFromString:timeStr];` this line converts the string to wrong date.. it gives 20-12-2015 16:52:22 +0000 as the result..
Where am I going wrong please help....

Comment: Did you search for questions relating to string/date conversion?  There's only about 50,000 of them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this to **`yyyy`** instead of **`YYYY`**

```
[dateform setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

"YYYY" is week-based calendar year.

"yyyy" is ordinary calendar year.

Then, check this format :: **`"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm:ss a"`**

```
if(is12h)
{
    [dateform setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
}
else
{
    [dateform setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
}
```

Comment: problem in  `NSDate *dt=[dateform dateFromString:timeStr];` not after check once and update your answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Oh okay.. Sorry.. I have updated my answer

Comment: @Prarthana keep coding ;) (y)

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

So in your case please try by using small "yyyy" instead

Answer (score 0):

here is the methods I prepared for date converting

```
+(NSString *)convertDate:(NSString *)strDate fromFormat:(NSString *)strFromFormat toFormat:(NSString *)strToFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strFromFormat;
    NSDate *dtNew = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strToFormat;
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dtNew];
}

+(NSString *)convertDateToString:(NSDate *)strDate toFormat:(NSString *)strToFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strToFormat;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:strDate]];
}


+(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *)strDate fromFormat:(NSString *)strFromFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = strFromFormat;
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
}
```

put these methods in one class & call it by class whenever you want...

For your problem, call this method like..

```
NSDate *dtnew = [YourClass convertStringToDate:timeStr fromFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: i tried this one,it throws an error unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this man,

```
NSString *dateString =  @"01-01-2016 22:22";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```